# What is the correct way to respond if an answer has biased views?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

What is the correct way to respond to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52435909/4316060)?

The responder has answered the question. But the answer contains a remark that seems biased and I'm not sure why it is there or whether it is even relevant for the question.

What should I do in this case? Comment on the answer (which will end up with a chain)? Downvote the answer? Or flag it? Or do nothing at all since it is the responder's right to have this opinion?

Comment: If you disagree with the answer, you can always downvote it.  Flags aren't for incorrect answers, and you already know the risk of commenting.

Comment: However, I wouldn't recommend answering that question as it is off topic, given it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: You unleashed the meta effect on this Q+A.  Ugly as usual.  I'll try to rescue it.

Comment: @HansPassant  I apologize for my mistake. I shouldn't have tagged the post I only wanted to know what is an acceptable way to respond.

Comment: I honestly don't see the controversy in my original answer. The question asked the correct way to create a helper object and I showed them how to do it non OO and do it functionally.The statement that the future of JavaScript is functional and not OO would be agreed by most people paying attention to the JavaScript space. Writing a helper object or reaching for a for loop would probably blow a technical interview for you these days so I see it as something that most people should at least pay attention to.

Comment: @AdrianBrand  I raised this question for my knowledge on how to respond in future when i see biased claims. I do apologize for tagging your answer. But your answer is controversial and is  biased. JS is a multi paradigm language and you should choose right tool for the right job. yes "Writing a helper object or reaching for a for loop would probably blow a technical interview"  i wouldn't write it or recommend it also but that are two valid scenarios for which you claim entirety of JS future changes (your claim wont change this but still) and it does sound like all or nothing.

Comment: @AdrianBrand `"[...] by most people paying attention to the JavaScript space."` That is the controversial part. That literally means "Everyone that does not agree with me hasn't been paying attention". That's... crab shit, to put it mildly :) And btw, the reason not to use "Helper" in class names is because it's a code smell of horrible design, in any language. Anyone actually knowing OOP would know that.

Comment: This really shouldn't be closed as opinion-based, but rather as an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29893591/es6-modules-export-single-class-of-static-methods-or-multiple-individual-method/29895235#29895235). Please help me reopen.

Comment: @ShyamBabu The claim might be too strong, and the OO part of JS will stay an important part, but in this particular situation the answer is correct - one should export named functions, not an object (or worse, a `class`).

Comment: @AdrianBrand I've rolled back Hans' edit, especially the first part of the removed passage was an essential part of the answer. You could (should?) have done the same. Feel free to defuse the part about the "future of javascript" if you want.

Comment: "essential"... well. not really. It's quite a good exemple of something that is "accessory" to the answer. It's a viewpoint (that I happen to share), but not "essential" @Bergi.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The question is asking "*Why should I use/not use this code?*", and Adrian answered with "*Don't use a `class` for a helper object*". This reason for favouring named exports is the main part of the answer imo, not the code example.

Comment: Ah yes, I can agree with that @Bergi. Wasn't really seeing the question in that light.

Comment: @Bergi maybe i wasn't clear. I agree with the answer technical code part, the point  i don't agree with the accessory claim "The future of JavaScript programming is functional not OO." which seems a very big claim on a public forum. So I raised this meta Q exactly because the answer was right and there was a biased view added to it. Then how should it be handled? Can i add a correct answer and keep adding any biased view as i want?Is this ok from SO meta point of view? if not how is downvote correct or not? nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @ShyamBabu Yes, you can do any of those, vote, comment, write your own better answer, or do nothing. Don't flag it. Up- and downvotes are always subjective, there is no right or wrong with them.

Comment: @ShyamBabu Personally, in such situations I usually comment that "*I would have upvoted if not for…*". A few would edit their answer to get the upvote, others would simply agree to disagree. I tend not to downvote technically correct answers, but that's just me.

Comment: The statement the future of JavaScript is functional not OO was not meant as an all or nothing statement. It should have read you should favour functional programming over OO. Use OO where it makes sense but creating a helper class doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7):

That post made a pretty wild claim.

Since this garnered some attention from meta, I noticed that Hans edited out the quote, which is fine. Sometimes it can make sense to edit out wild claims. However, that can lead to edit wars in some circumstances so it is best to use that option with a little reserve.

For what it's worth though, this is what it used to look like:

> The future of JavaScript programming is functional not OO.

It has since been removed and in its current state the answer takes a more neutral tone.

I won't get into the veracity of the quoted claim. In general, I would just downvote if you disagree with the claim enough that it overshadows the rest of the content, and move on to other posts. This one low viewed answer isn't going to change the future of JavaScript, trust me.

As for flagging, this *is* an answer. While it might (at one time) have contained an off-the-cuff remark, even at that point it was still legitimately an answer to the question since it included a coded response as well. Do not flag a post like this, unless the remark is in violation of the Be Nice policy on the site.

Comment: Not much point in editing when you preserve the controversy in a meta post.

Comment: @HansPassant It isn't like the revision was scrubbed from history.

Comment: @HansPassant - It isn't in the answer in its current state though, so I think your effort was still warranted. If the author were to revert your edit then I would agree.

Comment: @HansPassant - I edited my answer to at least diminish the controversial content.

Comment: The comment wasn't made as an all or nothing statement, of course there will still be OO parts to JavaScript programming, but making a helper object in a technical test these days would most likely blow the job interview for you so it definitely was relevant to the question.